# Filter n arrays by excluding values that don't exist in each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have *n* arrays with which I need to determine if *x* is in all of the *n* arrays. (where *n* is any number, and *x* is a numeric value) I have something like the following in place, but it's always ending up false.

```
function filterArrays()
{
  var x = $(this).attr('id'); // ex: 2
  var arrays = [[1,2,3],[2,4,6]];
  var result = false;
  for each (var n in arrays)
  {
    result = result ^ (n.indexOf(x) > -1);
  }
}
```

How do I make `result` equal to `true` when `x` is in both arrays, but when `x` is not in both arrays, make `result` equal to `false`?

The function above will be used with jQuery's `filter()` method. Example:

```
$(arrayOfElementsWithNumericIds).filter(arrayFilter);
// arrayOfElementsWithNumericIds prototype: [div#1,div#2,div#3,...]
```

I'm thinking that a bitwise operation is called for, but I could be wrong. Please explain *why* your solution is right and why mine isn't working. (for bonus points)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some issues with your example:

- Comparing number to string (id is a string).  Use `x = parseInt(...)`
- Using the `^` operator.  Instead initialize `result` to `true` and use `&&`.
- Get rid of `each`.  The correct syntax is `for (key in object)`

I've modified your code as little as possible:

```
function filterArrays()
{
    var x = parseInt($(this).attr('id')); // ex: 2
    var arrays = [[1,2,3],[2,4,6]];
    var result = true;
    for (var n in arrays)
    {
        result = result && (arrays[n].indexOf(x) > -1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

That being said, you can really optimize your code by using [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).  Also, using `$(this).attr('id')` creates a jQuery object unnecessarily since you can just say `this.id` directly.

```
function filterArrays()
{
    var x = parseInt(this.id); // ex: 2
    var arrays = [[1,2,3],[2,4,6]];
    var result = arrays.every(function(array)
    {
        return array.some(function(item)
        {
            return item === x;
        });
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions on how I could improve my code. While I would disagree on your use of the quantifier "lots" with regard to the errors in my example, I appreciate you pointing out the "few" you found and explaining how/why they could be improved. Your answer was the most thorough and therefore is the one I will accept. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @sholsinger: Thanks.  I didn't mean anything by "lots"... You are right, "few" is more accurate. :-)

Comment: My actual set-up is different. In my real code, `arrays` is an object, and therefore doesn't support `every()`. Is there a way that I can convert the object to an array without incurring too much overhead?

Comment: @sholsinger: You could, but it wouldn't buy you much, if anything at all.  For iterating an object, using `for ... in` as you already have should be good enough.  The only thing I'd add is a `break` statement in your loop if `result` is false.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for this:

```
  var result = true;
 for each (var n in arrays)
  {
    result = result && (n.indexOf(x) > -1);
  }
```

That is, assume that the value is in all the arrays to start. Then using the AND (&&) operator you get

```
  true AND (value is in current array)
```

if at any time the value is not in an array it becomes false and the entire operation will be false. Otherwise it remains true until the end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks you probably already know, but your answer is correct and would fix the example code I provided. I appreciate the time you spent crafting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

xor's not the way to go. Look at it this way:

```
search for 2, start  result = false
1st array: 2 is present, result = false xor true = true
2nd array: 2 is present, result = true xor true = false
end: result is false (WRONG)

search for 4, start result = false
1st array: 4 is present, result = false xor true = true
2nd array: 4 is  absent, result = true xor false = true
end: result is true (WRONG)
```

You want a cummulative bit-wise and.

```
start: result = true, search for 2
1st array: 2 is present, result = true and true = true
2nd array: 2 is present, result = true and true = true
end: result is true (RIGHT)

start: result = true, search for 4
1st array: 4 is present, result = true and true = true
2nd array: 4 is absent, result = true and false = false
end: result if false (RIGHT)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on changing from an XOR to AND. That is technically correct and would have fixed the problem. (mostly) Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you extend the array prototype with a contains method? that way you can loop over each array and or/and the current result with the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your 'arrays' object if you want, but, I think you just want a Set Intersect operation.  This is one way to do it in jQuery, and it won't care about if the attr(id) value of x is an integer or string.  I'm on lunch, i'll test this in a page quick...

```
function filterArrays(){
  var x = $(this).attr("id");
  var arrays = [[1,2,3],[2,4,6]];
  var result = ($.inArray(arrays[0], x )>0 && $.inArray(arrays[1], x) >0);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @marc b I agree, cumulative bit-wise and operation.  my post is an n^2 solution afaik.

Comment: See the two different Set implementations in my answer for pre-written code.

Answer (score 0):

Using http://phrogz.net/JS/ArraySetMath.js you could:

```
var sets  = [[1,2,3],[2,3,7],[1,7,2]];
var isect = sets[0];
for (var i=1,len=sets.length;i<len;++i){
  isect = isect.intersection( sets[i] );
}
console.log( isect );
// [2]
```

Or, using [JS.Set](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/set.html) you could:

```
var sets  = [[1,2,3],[2,3,7],[1,7,2]];

// Or JS.HashSet or JS.Set
var isect = new JS.SortedSet(sets[0]);
for (var i=1,len=sets.length;i<len;++i){
  isect = isect.intersection( new JS.SortedSet(sets[i]) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the effort you've put into making that library. That said, I don't want to add any additional overhead to my script at this time.